# How to sort two array in the same manner?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have two lists and fancy to sort them according to the first one. I get indexes how the first array s was sorted. How to apply the same order/the list of indexes to the s2, please?

```
s = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3]
sorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda k: s[k]) 
>>[2, 0, 1, 5, 3, 4]
```

`s1 = [20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 3`0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this shoud work

```
res = []
for i in range(len(s1)):
    res[i] = s1[s[i]]
```